# How to insert an element at the end of array in java? This is my code which is showing ArrayindexBoundOfException

Tags: java, arrays, insert

I'm a new programmer in java. 
How to insert a new element into the array at the user want.
here is the code which is showing error:

```
import java.util.*;
public class insertion{

public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("pls enter the size of an array:-->");
int n=in.nextInt();

int num[]=new int[n];

for(int k=0;k<num.length;k++)
{
    System.out.println("enter the value:--> "+(k+1));
    num[k]=in.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("Enter the number to be inserted:-->");
int m=in.nextInt();

for(int j=0;j<num.length-1;j++)
{
    num[j]=num[j+1];
    j=j--;
    num[j]=m;

}

for(int p=0;p<num.length+1;p++)
    System.out.println(num[p]); 
}
}
```

error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at insertion.insertion.main(insertion.java:29)

Comment: Please post the error and which line the error is referring to

Comment: Java arrays are not *dynamic*. If you want a dynamic data structure use a `Collection` like an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert a new element in arrays in java. size of array in java are static.
You will have to create new array or you can use **Collection framework** (*no need to create new array*) or **Arrays** class (*new array will be created*).

Using Collection framework :

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(20);
list.add(30);
```

Using Arrays class :

```
int[] list = {20}
list = Arrays.copyOf(list, list.length + 1);
list[list.length - 1] = 30;
```

Comment: @verma i don't want to use ArrayList in my core

Comment: then the second method would be just fine for you. @Verma isn't it?